# TableView losing selected row on back in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a navigation controller and two view controllers attached to it `ViewController1`and `ViewController2`. When This is the code snippet where I set the selected row

```
  func questions()
  { // Initalizations
   var ns = defaults.integerForKey(qwre)
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: ns, inSection: 0)
   self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    }
```

The row is getting selected fine whenever `ViewController1` is loaded.

This is my function viewdidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
questions()
 }
```

Now the problem is whenever I go back from `ViewController2`to `ViewController1`. I am not getting the row selected. Obviously viewDidLoad() is not being called. Where should I keep the code so that `questions` is called whenever I go back

Comment: **viewDidAppear** will be a ideal candidate in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your method with `viewDidAppear()` like

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    questions()
}
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Thanks. Also when `ViewController1` is loaded, does it mean questions would be called twice. Should I remove `questions` from viewDidLoad()?

Comment: It is better to remove from `viewdidload()`, coz ultimately `viewDidAppear()` will call the function every time when view apear, whether first or again, it will call.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the function you are using in `viewDidLoad` and put it in `viewDidAppear`.

`viewDidLoad` is only called when you create the view for example show it, but if you `pop back` `viewDidLoad` will not be called but `viewWillAppear` will be called instead. So putting the function in `viewWillAppear` will fix your problem and in order to make it be called only once, remove it from `viewDidLoad`.
Hope it helps and makes your concept clear.